# What step am I missing to check if value matches array element and print an alert using if/else

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to check user input against predetermined list of zipcodes. I've created one variable that represents the user input using `document.getElementById("zipcode").value` and set up my array of zipcodes to check against. This worked once but I think I had `break;` included in the if/else. What am I missing?
The input box translates to a string so I made my array elements string too. I'm so confused.

```
<h2>Zipcode checker</h2>

<input id="zipcode" name="address-4" type=text maxlength="5" value="" pattern="[0-9]" required/>`
<button id="btn" value="submit" type="submit" onclick="myStuff()">Register</button>
```

Script:

```
var btnInput = document.getElementById("zipcode").value;
var acceptedZip = ["85392", "85340", "85393", "85353", "85341"];
function myStuff() {
    for (var i = 0; i < acceptedZip.length; i++) {
        if (acceptedZip[i] === btnInput) {
            alert("we got you boo");
         } 
         else {
            alert("sorry son");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `function myStuff() { return acceptedZip.includes(btnInput) }` <- tada

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you're storing the value of the input only once, which is when the code is runs for the first time, and the value at the first run is empty `""` (if you don't set it in html).

You can do what you want with just this :

```html
<h2>Zipcode checker</h2>

<input id="zipcode" name="address-4" type=text maxlength="5" value="" pattern="[0-9]" required/>`
<button id="btn" value="submit" type="submit" onclick="myStuff()">Register</button>

<script>
  var btnInput = document.getElementById("zipcode"); // store the button outside
  var acceptedZip = ["85392", "85340", "85393", "85353", "85341"];
  function myStuff() {
      var exists = acceptedZip.indexOf(btnInput.value)>-1 ; // get the value of the input inside (each time the button is pressed)
      alert(exists ? "we got you boo" : "sorry son");
  }
</script>
```

I'm using JavaScript's ternary operator, which is basically :

```
<cond 1> ? <act 1> : <cond 2> ? <act 2> : <act 3>
equivalent to :
if (<cond 1>) { act 1 } else if (<cond 2>) { <act 2> } else { <act 3> }
```